# Asp.NET WebForm How to remove a control from submit

Tags: asp.net, http, webforms, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I've a very complex Asp.NET 4.0 application, with a particular form builded with Telerik RadControls.

There's a RadGrid with nested RadGrid, with rows composed by various TextBoxes (RadTextBox, etc...).

This form is HUGE, and when it grows, if I post the page (asynch or not), I get an error inside the **Application_BeginRequest**, the stack is:

```
in System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded()
in System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
in System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
```

I know there's a limit of 1000 items postable in a web form, and I know this limit is configurable via web.config.

I DON'T need to post these controls: I used them to enable the client-side features of the Telerik controls, so I wonder: there is a way to specifically remove a control or a set of controls from the HttpValueCollection in order to reduce the number of items?

Many thanks!

**UPDATE**: As @Alex suggest I've implemented a function to disable all the input inside my grid:

```
function disableAllGridsControls() {
    $("input[id*=gridServiziCommessa]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

this solves the problem with the standard postback, BUT not with an ajax update.
The Grid is ajaxified by a Telerik control called RadAjaxManager, that extends the standard ASP.NET Ajax.
This control exposes a [BeginRequest event](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-onrequeststart.html), so I'm trying to call the disableAllGridsControls during this event:

```
function ajaxManager_beginRequest(sender, args) {
    disableAllGridsControls();
}
```

but simply doesn't work... looking with fiddler I still see ALL THE INPUTS posted during the AJAX call....

And there's another weird behaviour: if I disable the grid Server-side (Enabled="False") and make an AJAX call, the inputs are posted anyway.

What I'm missing?

**UPDATE2** Ok, I'm pretty sure the problem resides in the MicrosoftAjax framework or in the RadAjaxManager, wich is based upon it. It seems that the parameter collection builded to perform the ajax request IGNORES the fact the inputs are disabled... weird...

Answer (score 1):

You could [disable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#disabled) your controls then [they won't be successful](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) (controls that are disabled cannot be successful) and hence won't be submitted.

It could be done both on client- and server-side.

- On the server-side set the [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled.aspx) property of the parent control to `true` - this will disable all the textboxes, dropdowns etc. inside it.
- On the client-side it could be done e.g. by disabling necessary controls during the form submit.

Here is a very simple example of how it could be done on the client-side by using jQuery:

```
$('#theForm').submit(function () {
    $(this).find('[name^="<%= yourGrid.UniqueID %>"]')
        .attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    return true;
});
```

Here I disable all the controls which `name` attribute starts with `yourGrid` (assuming, this is a naming container) value.

Despite of this I suppose changing the maximum numbers of posting values through `web.config` is a best option.

Comment: Many thanks! It works fine with normal postback, but can't do the same in an ajax scenario. I've updated the question to explain...